# Marcar automaticamente checkbox da data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho 3 `checkbox` e 2 `inputs`. A segunda `checkbox`  é `parent()` do 1 `input type number` e a terceira `checkbox`  é `parent()` do 1 `input type number`:

```
$calendar .= "<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''><font size='2px'/> 
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> <strong style='color:#5ca2df'>$year-$month-$day</strong> <br /> 
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div>
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'><input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> <strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço</strong></div> <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'><input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> </div></font></center></td>";}
```

Para marcar automaticamente a 2 e 3 `checkbox` ao colocar um valor maior que zero no `input type number` tenho este `script`:

```
<script> 
var inputs_ = document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']"); 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 

inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 

var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 
box.checked = this.value > 0 ? true : false; 

}); 

}
</script>
```

Ao preencher o 1 ou 2 input type number, além de marcar automaticamente a `checkbox` `parent()` dele, quero que também marque automatica a primeira `checkbox` da data.
É possível adaptar o meu script para fazer isso?

**A resposta do @osiris85 funciona no exemplo que ele deu, mas ao aplica-la no meu código existe um problema, vou passar a explicar.**

Se aplicar no meu código a resposta do @osiris85, ao preencher os `inputs`, só selecciona a data do dia 1 e não a data de acordo com o dia onde o `input` se encontra.
Por exemplo: preencho os `inputs` do dia 2018-11-18 e marca automaticamente só a `checkbox` do dia 2018-11-01

Como mostro na imagem:
[image: Exemplo do problema]

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você pode verificar que sempre um dos valores é positivo caso todos sejam negativos ele seria descartado. Para fazer isso, você deve atribuir um ID à caixa de combinação e marcá-lo ou desmarcá-lo, dependendo do valor do resto.

```js
var inputs_ = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='number'][name^='arrachar']")]; 
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){ 
  inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){ 
    var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']"); 
    
    box.checked = !getValuesLessorEqualZero([this]);
    
    var firstBox = document.getElementById('firstCB');
    firstBox.checked =true;

    var valueAllLessOrZero = getValuesLessorEqualZero(inputs_);
    if(valueAllLessOrZero) firstBox.checked = false;
  }); 
}

const getValuesLessorEqualZero = (inputs) => {
  var lengthInputs = inputs.length;
  var valueLessOrZero = true;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < lengthInputs && valueLessOrZero; i++) {
    valueLessOrZero = inputs[i].value <= 0 ? true : false;
  }

  return valueLessOrZero;
};
```

```html
<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''>
<font size='2px'/> 
<input id='firstCB' type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> 
<strong style='color:#5ca2df'>$year-$month-$day</strong> 
<br /> 
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'>
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> 
<strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong>
</div> 
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
<input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> 
<br /> 
</div>
<div style='width:60%;position:relative;float:left'>
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> 
<strong style='color: #000000'>Almoço</strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
<input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> 
<br /> 
</div>
```

Comment: verifico que aqui está a dar o resultado que pretendo, mas aplicando no meu código a checkbox continua sem aparecer marcada

Comment: adcionó o id ao input `<input id='firstCB' type='checkbox`?

Comment: sim adicionei ao html

Comment: tente remover os 3 tags `</font></center></td>`

Comment: o resultado é o mesmo...

Comment: te algum erro na consola do desenvolvedor?

Comment: não dá erro nenhum na consola e afinal selecciona a data. Mas existe um problema, eu coloco valor em diferentes inputs, só seleciona a data do dia 1 e não a data em que se encontra o input. Por exemplo, coloco valor no input do dia 24 e seleciona a data do dia 1. Editei a pergunta com a outra parte do código.